# PSD of random track inputs

Tags: matlab, psd

I am currently modelling a train on MATLAB/SIMULINK.
The article i following is:

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40864-016-0045-x

In the article track profile is represented by 2 slope power slope density(PSD) as the equation below:
[equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkFay.png)

PSD of the track is represented as the equation below also:

[psd equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQL2Q.png)  where the Av is 0.0339 and the wc is 0.8245.

Regarding this PSD plot is found in article is:

[PSD plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeMrZ.png)

I wrote the MATLAB code below for the same equation as below. However i found completely different plotting.
Can you help me about that what do you think i did wrong.

```
clc
clear all
%% PSD of track profile
f = 0:0.5:100;            %Hz
% Av=0.0339;              %Track condition identifier (cm2rad/m)
Av=0.0339*(10e-4)/(2*pi); %m2Hz/m
%wc=0.8245;               %Constant pulsation for rail irregularity (rad/m)
fc=0.8245/(2*pi);         %(Hz/m)   

S=(0.25*Av.*fc.^2)./((f.^2+fc.^2).*f.^2);
semilogx(f, S)
xlabel('frequency [Hz]')
ylabel('power spectral density of track profile [m2/Hz]')
grid on
```

My plotting:
[my plotting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7syr.png)

Comment: There may be other issues, but the plot linked from the paper is loglog, whereas yours is semilogx

Comment: Thanks luis. I did not even notice it.

Comment: Can you help me out writing it in time domain

Comment: Sorry, I would have to read the paper to understand what you want. Try to phrase _specifically_ what you need and post it as a question